# comapare file1 with 12 file then copy the matched records one file and unmatch records other files using jcl

Tags: jcl

could you please help to get results for below requirement

- the file 1 having only 18 fixed length data to compare with file 2
- if any matching records 
  then copy the complete matching record from file 2 to output1 and 
  the non-matching records from file 1 and file 2 to other output2
- input1 file length 18
  input2 file length 503

i have joined 12 files into single file like this

```
STEP001   EXEC PGM=SORT                                        
SORTJNF1  DD DSN=XXX.Q.KR0Z2R99.XXXX.ISA.OUP(0),DISP=SHR   
SORTJNF2  DD DSN=xxx.P.K0101N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K3211N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K2912N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K0618N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K3720N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K4731N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K0242N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K4451N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K1256N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K4560N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K1961N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
          DD DSN=xxx.P.K3290N00.xxxx11P1.xxxxXTO(0),DISP=SHR  
SORTOUT   DD DSN=XXX.Q.KR0Z2R99.XXX.MAT.OUP(+1),          
             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                          
             DCB=(LRECL=261,BLKSIZE=0,RECFM=FB),               
             SPACE=(CYL,(20,10),RLSE)                          
SYSPRINT  DD SYSOUT=*                        
SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*                        
SYSIN     DD *                               
 JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,18,A)            
 JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(1,18,A)            
 JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2                         
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F2:1,258,F2:264,1,F2:334,2)
 SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

here just i tried to copy the only matching records but the out file  got complete records from input2

Comment: So what is not working? State your problem clearer.

Comment: iam not getting matching records. my intention was only matching records to copy to out put file

Comment: Which of the methods, for which there are examples in the DFSort manual, have you tried? Why the JCL tag - this is a DFSort question not a JCL question. JCL cannot do what you want. People looking to answer or seek solutions to sort questions will look for the DFsort tag. So improve your chances of getting a sloution by changing the tag.