# compare two files then put matched records into one file and unmatched records into another file

Tags: dfsort

I have requirement to compare two files then matched records one file and unmatched into another file using joinkeys in jcl
I'm not sure whether this is the correct one or not. Could you, please, help me?

```
JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,18,A)                      
JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(1,18,A)                      
JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2                                   
REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,100,F2:1,503,?)                 
SORT FIELDS=COPY                                      
OUTFIL FNAMES=NOMATCH,INCLUDE=(604,1,SS,EQ,C'1,2'),   
IFTHEN=(WHEN=(604,1,CH,EQ,C'1'),                      
                BUILD=(1:1,258,260:264,1,263:334,2)), 
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,                              
                BUILD=(604,603))                      
   OUTFIL FNAMES=MATCH,SAVE,                          
      BUILD=(1:1,258,260:264,1,263:334,2)
```

Comment: First, this is not a JCL problem so drop the JCL tag and replace with the DFsort tag because it is a sort control statements question and they are not JCL. Second, why not try it using test data and if it does not do what you want come back with HOW it did not meet your requirement.

Comment: isn't this the same question you asked yesterday? like exactly the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comapare file1 with 12 file then copy the matched records one file and unmatch records other files using jcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761373/comapare-file1-with-12-file-then-copy-the-matched-records-one-file-and-unmatch-r)

Comment: i didnot get the answer yet...

Comment: @maheshKumar - people respond IF they want to and on their own time and without pay. If you need to get a quick answer then hire an expert. And you are less likely to get a response to a DFSort question if you tag it JCL and not DFSORT. So fix that tag.

Comment: @MaheshKumar that does not mean post another question.